# String indices must be integers json python

Tags: python, json

I've been trying to get the name "John" in the category "role" but I am keep getting this error: String indices must be integers. Ive been having a lot of trouble lately decoding this.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "group": {
        "id": 7748990,
        "name": "GroupName",
        "memberCount": 493
      },
      "role": {
        "id": 48442149,
        "name": "John",
        "rank": 5
      }
    }
```

My code:

```
r = requests.request("GET",url,params=payload)
    r_format = json.loads(r.text)
    data = json.dumps(r_format,indent=2)
    print(data['data']['role'][0])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `print(data['data'][0]['role'])`

Comment: with request you should just be able to do `r.json()` and then like flakes said `data['data'][0]['role']['name']` because the inner data is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `print(data['data']['role'][0])` with:

```
print(data['data'][0]['role']['name'])
```

Here is a working example:

```
r_format = {
  "data": [
    {
      "group": {
        "id": 7748990,
        "name": "GroupName",
        "memberCount": 493
      },
      "role": {
        "id": 48442149,
        "name": "John",
        "rank": 5
      }
    }
  ]
}

print('The name you are looking for is %s' % (r_format['data'][0]['role']['name']))
```

->

```
The name you are looking for is John
```